# Wrong coordinate transformation with osr.CoordinateTransformation

Tags: transform, gdal, epsg

I'm running a Python script (Python 3.9.16) in ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS. I'm doing it through Docker, althouh I've doubble-checked in Jupyter Notebook and I'm obtaining the same result.
I want to transform a bounding box from lat long coordinates (EPSG 4326) to EPSG 32630, but the resulting coordinates are wrong. I'm not getting any errors or warnings.

```
from osgeo import ogr, osr, gdal

bbox=[-7.84831, 39.71484, -7.73302, 39.81967]

sourceSR = osr.SpatialReference()
sourceSR.ImportFromEPSG(4326) # WGS84 lat lon
targetSR = osr.SpatialReference()
targetSR.ImportFromEPSG(32630)  # WGS84 / UTM zone 30N
coordTrans = osr.CoordinateTransformation(sourceSR, targetSR)
minX_lon, minY_lat, maxX_lon, maxY_lat = bbox
minX, minY, _ = coordTrans.TransformPoint(minX_lon, minY_lat)
maxX, maxY, _ = coordTrans.TransformPoint(maxX_lon, maxY_lat)
trans_bbox = [minX, minY, maxX, maxY]
print(trans_bbox)
```

The resulting coordinates are: [5696620.047694968, -1177782.6621069708, 5714320.913186516, -1162605.0876848244] and the ones I would expect are: [84341.6581044693, 4407359.8613803, 94846.54347402562, 4418472.2108658375].

I've verified that the X coordinates correspond to longitude and the Y coordinates correspond to latitude. Despite this, I'm still unable to identify what I might be missing. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the solution!

[Before GDAL 3.0 the axis order was longitude first, latitude later. Starting with GDAL 3.0 CRS created with the "EPSG:4326" or "WGS84" strings use the latitude first, longitude second axis order](https://gdal.org/tutorials/osr_api_tut.html#crs-and-axis-order)

With `oSRS.SetAxisMappingStrategy(OAMS_TRADITIONAL_GIS_ORDER)` you can set the proper order.

I edited my code:

```
sourceSR = osr.SpatialReference()
sourceSR.ImportFromEPSG(4326) # WGS84 lat lon
sourceSR.SetAxisMappingStrategy(osr.OAMS_TRADITIONAL_GIS_ORDER)
targetSR.ImportFromEPSG(32630)  # WGS84 / UTM zone 30N
coordTrans = osr.CoordinateTransformation(sourceSR, targetSR)
minX_lon, minY_lat, maxX_lon, maxY_lat = bbox
minX, minY, _ = coordTrans.TransformPoint(minX_lon, minY_lat)
maxX, maxY, _ = coordTrans.TransformPoint(maxX_lon, maxY_lat)
trans_bbox = [minX, minY, maxX, maxY]
print(trans_bbox)
```

The resulting coordinates are now as expected. I hope this can help someone else.